# How to check if a list item has a checkbox in orgmode

Tags: org-mode

I am attempting to write a convenience function that would, on an item in an orgmode list, insert a checkbox if there is none, and do nothing otherwise.

The question is how would I be able to test for the existence of a checkbox in a list item?

I'm aware of testing for a list item via `org-in-item-p`, but am unable to find a similar predicate for checkboxes.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What version of `orgmode` are you on? In `orgmode 8.2.10`, there is `org-at-item-checkbox-p`.

Comment: I have no idea. How do I check?

Comment: `M-x org-version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a remotely recent version of Orgmode, you should have the function `org-at-item-checkbox-p` in `org-list.el`.

Look in your `org-list.el` to see if it's there. If not, update to a more recent version of Orgmode, or implement it yourself:

```el
(defun org-at-item-checkbox-p ()
  "Is point at a line starting a plain-list item with a checklet?"
  (org-list-at-regexp-after-bullet-p "\\(\\[[- X]\\]\\)[ \t]+"))
```